# Set sidebar height equal with content on scroll

Tags: jquery, css

sometimes my content div's height is greater than sidebar height and its not good looking.

**I want to do if content height is greater than sidebar, on page scroll add margin-top to sidebar until bottom of the content**

I tried to do that with this code:

```
var sidebar = $("#sidebar").outerHeight();
var content = $("#content-left").outerHeight();
var gap = (content - sidebar);
$(window).scroll(function() {
if ($(this).scrollTop() > gap) { 
if (content > sidebar ) {
$("#sidebar").css('margin-top', +gap);
}}});
```

But it is not actually what I want to do. I want if user scrolled 20px, add 20px margin until bottom of the content.

If there is more easy and good way to do this, please let me know.

Thanks for help!

**UPDATE:**

Here is my #content-left css : `#content-left { float: left;width: 68%;}`

and #sidebar css :

```
float: right;
width: 30%;
height: auto;
padding: 0;
margin-top: 0px;
margin-bottom: 15px;
overflow: hidden;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I decided to improve the answer (after it was accepted). Now I have created a function, which will handle positioning of the div. You can run it on scrolling, window resizing, etc. I figured this would be very useful in case anyone wanted to use this code.

Just change the variables:

- contentHeight
- sidebarHeight
- contentOffset

And you're all done :).

Suggestions on further improvements on this are always welcome.

**JS-Fiddle**

[JS-Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uzfxg6zz/9/)

**html**

```
<header>
<h1>"The sticking sidebar"</h1>
</header>
<div id="content"><p>START<br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus a tellus tincidunt, lacinia ex facilisis, facilisis ipsum. Pellentesque ac accumsan mi. Vestibulum iaculis luctus ultricies. Integer aliquet, felis id facilisis consectetur, tortor ligula eleifend urna, convallis facilisis erat erat nec libero. Pellentesque finibus sed leo vel tincidunt. Praesent in est erat. Donec nec varius leo. Nam convallis feugiat velit at commodo. Mauris feugiat lorem eros, a varius sem gravida eu. Ut convallis, velit hendrerit semper laoreet, libero nunc egestas neque, et ultrices ex elit et lacus.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus a tellus tincidunt, lacinia ex facilisis, facilisis ipsum. Pellentesque ac accumsan mi. Vestibulum iaculis luctus ultricies. Integer aliquet, felis id facilisis consectetur, tortor ligula eleifend urna, convallis facilisis erat erat nec libero. Pellentesque finibus sed leo vel tincidunt. Praesent in est erat. Donec nec varius leo. Nam convallis feugiat velit at commodo. Mauris feugiat lorem eros, a varius sem gravida eu. Ut convallis, velit hendrerit semper laoreet, libero nunc egestas neque, et ultrices ex elit et lacus.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus a tellus tincidunt, lacinia ex facilisis, facilisis ipsum. Pellentesque ac accumsan mi. Vestibulum iaculis luctus ultricies. Integer aliquet, felis id facilisis consectetur, tortor ligula eleifend urna, convallis facilisis erat erat nec libero. Pellentesque finibus sed leo vel tincidunt. Praesent in est erat. Donec nec varius leo. Nam convallis feugiat velit at commodo. Mauris feugiat lorem eros, a varius sem gravida eu. Ut convallis, velit hendrerit semper laoreet, libero nunc egestas neque, et ultrices ex elit et lacus.</p><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus a tellus tincidunt, lacinia ex facilisis, facilisis ipsum. Pellentesque ac accumsan mi. Vestibulum iaculis luctus ultricies. Integer aliquet, felis id facilisis consectetur, tortor ligula eleifend urna, convallis facilisis erat erat nec libero. Pellentesque finibus sed leo vel tincidunt. Praesent in est erat. Donec nec varius leo. Nam convallis feugiat velit at commodo. Mauris feugiat lorem eros, a varius sem gravida eu. Ut convallis, velit hendrerit semper laoreet, libero nunc egestas neque, et ultrices ex elit et lacus.<br/>END</p></div>
<div id="sidebar"><p>START<br/> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus a tellus tincidunt, lacinia ex facilisis, facilisis ipsum. Pellentesque ac accumsan mi. Vestibulum iaculis luctus ultricies. Integer aliquet, felis id facilisis consectetur, tortor ligula eleifend urna, convallis facilisis erat erat nec libero. Pellentesque finibus sed leo vel tincidunt. Praesent in est erat. Donec nec varius leo. Nam convallis feugiat velit at commodo. Mauris feugiat lorem eros, a varius sem gravida eu. Ut convallis, velit hendrerit semper laoreet, libero nunc egestas neque, et ultrices ex elit et lacus.<br/>END</p></div>
<footer><i>footer</i></footer>
```

**css**

```
header h1{
  text-align: center;
}
#content{
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  background-color: rgb(150, 150, 0)
}
#sidebar{
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  float: right;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

**js/jQuery**

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  // define variables before scrollin to destress the processor
  let contentHeight = $("#content").height();
  let sidebarHeight = $("#sidebar").height();
  let windowHeight = $(window).height();
  let doc = $(document); 
  let contentOffset = $("#content").offset().top;

  $(window).resize(function(){
    //should reset all variables here or the code will bug out on screen resizing 
  contentHeight = $("#content").height();;
  sidebarHeight = $("#sidebar").height();
  windowHeight = $(window).height();
  contentOffset = $("#content").offset().top;
  determineSidebarScrollBehavior(doc, contentHeight, contentOffset, sidebarHeight,windowHeight);
  });
  $(document).scroll(function(){
            determineSidebarScrollBehavior(doc, contentHeight, contentOffset, sidebarHeight, windowHeight);
  }); // end scroll
});//end ready

function determineSidebarScrollBehavior(doc, contentHeight, contentOffset, sidebarHeight, windowHeight){ 
    //only run if the #sidebar is higher than the #content
  if(contentHeight>sidebarHeight){
    var scrollTop = doc.scrollTop();
    //check if variable has been previously created by this function else the value is 0
    let oldScrollTop = (window.oldScrollTop)?window.oldScrollTop:0;
    //create a marginTop var if it doesn t exist yet
    window.marginTop = (window.marginTop)?marginTop:0;
    //determine if you scroll up op down
    let isScrollingDown = (scrollTop>oldScrollTop)?true:false;
    //if the end of the sidebar reaches the end of the window change margin so it "sticks". It should stick until the #sidebar reaches the same height (inculding margin) as the #content.
    if(isScrollingDown && scrollTop+windowHeight > contentOffset + sidebarHeight + marginTop){
    marginTop = scrollTop + windowHeight-sidebarHeight-contentOffset;
    // check if content would be too long, if so set the maximum marginTop
    if(marginTop>contentHeight-sidebarHeight){
        marginTop = contentHeight-sidebarHeight;
      }
    }    
    // if the start of the sidebar reaches the top while scrolling up, make it "stick"
        else if(!isScrollingDown && scrollTop < contentOffset + marginTop){
        marginTop = scrollTop - contentOffset;
      // make sure margin-top cannot go negative
      if(marginTop<0){
        marginTop = 0;
      }
    }
    //change the margin
    $("#sidebar").css({'margin-top': marginTop});
  }
  window.oldScrollTop = scrollTop;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, your code works good but there is still some points to fix. I recorded a video with your code. [Please watch from here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PTCBxcdwK5c) . We need to add margin-top only when user see end of the sidebar. And as you see in the video, when scrolling back to top, sidebar isn't looking good. Still has margin-top. I hope I could explained. Thank you for help again :) @RMo

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uzfxg6zz/7/ It was a bit of work, but..this might be better. I noticed some severe lag in your video, so hopefully it lags a little less because of some additional optimisations. Give a comment if it works well and I ll update it to my answer.

Comment: This is a lot of work, really thank you for your help. Now, it works very well and better. I recorded a [video](https://youtu.be/BUpRen3OVck) again and I think there are two things to fix. First, on the 7. second, as you see when coming to bottom of the content, sidebar margin removes. Can it still go sticky until bottom of the content ? And again on the 9. second, sidebar sticks as when scrolling down. Can we stick top of the sidebar instead of bottom when scrolling top and can it go until top of the content in a sticky way ? Thank you again <3 @RMo

Comment: Looks like I forgot about the contentOffset in the condition. This looks better: https://jsfiddle.net/uzfxg6zz/8/. As for the scrolling upwards. I think it is possible, but you would have to detect if you are scrolling up or down, then go from there.

Comment: Thank you so much @RMo , it really works very well, I think you can edit your answer now. I appreciate for your help. <3

Comment: I decided to make the answer a bit better again. I created a function of the entire thing and added the behaviour you wanted when scrolling up. New JSFIddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uzfxg6zz/9/

Comment: Now, better than better :) thank you again. But it seems a bit laggy because of margin-top. If we use position:fixed it would be smooth but we cant use in this situtation. If it is possible could you please try to make this more smoother? @RMo

Answer (score 0):

You can use flex, and ditch the javascript. I've written a quick example for you below.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.sidebar {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 20%;
  background: pink;
}

.content {
  min-height: 100vh;
  width: 80%;
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="sidebar"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I have divs in sidebar and content, and if I add display:flex to content, all divs messing up like [this](http://prntscr.com/fvpvah) . I already checked other solutions on the web and none of them worked for me. I think only way to do this with margin-top for me :)

Comment: You should only add flex to the container, not the content container itself. @Solhan

Comment: I added display:flex; to only #content-left div . Am I doing mistake ?

Comment: Yes, can you please provide a more detailed example, and I can fix this for you. @Solhan